# How can I loop through the and adjust the variable every month in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to iterate though the data frame and apply similar logic to the divisor on the first day of each month.
Please note the '2017-01-01':'2017-01-31' have different logic which is a one time case since it is the start month.

I've tried for loop, but I got an unexpected outcome.

Here is what I have with the logic that I need, but I want it to be iterable.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date')

index_df['Divisor'].loc['2017-01-01':'2017-01-31'] = index_df['Total.Cap'].loc['2017-01-01']/1000

index_df['Divisor'].loc['2017-02-01':'2017-02-28'] = index_df['Divisor'].loc['2017-01-01'] * (index_df['Real.Cap'].loc['2017-02-01']/index_df['Total.Cap'].loc['2017-01-31'])

index_df['Divisor'].loc['2017-03-01':'2017-03-31'] = 
index_df['Divisor'].loc['2017-02-01'] * (index_df['Real.Cap'].loc['2017-03-01']/index_df['Total.Cap'].loc['2017-02-28'])
```

Here is the expected output: (please ignore BTC column)

```
            Total.Cap      Real.Cap       Divisor         Index       BTC
2017-01-01  1.786821e+10  1.786821e+10  1.786821e+07   1000.000000    998.33
2017-01-02  1.830125e+10  1.830378e+10  1.786821e+07   1024.235071   1021.75
2017-01-03  1.879293e+10  1.879827e+10  1.786821e+07   1051.752401   1043.84
2017-01-04  2.081866e+10  2.082756e+10  1.786821e+07   1165.122880   1154.73
2017-01-05  1.836418e+10  1.837429e+10  1.786821e+07   1027.757315   1013.38
2017-01-06  1.649646e+10  1.650785e+10  1.786821e+07    923.229396    902.20
2017-01-07  1.654743e+10  1.656090e+10  1.786821e+07    926.082111    908.59
2017-01-08  1.663336e+10  1.664929e+10  1.786821e+07    930.891282    911.20
2017-01-09  1.651083e+10  1.652868e+10  1.786821e+07    924.034021    902.83
2017-01-10  1.662196e+10  1.664233e+10  1.786821e+07    930.253315    907.68
2017-01-11  1.435626e+10  1.437583e+10  1.786821e+07    803.452522    777.76
2017-01-12  1.483227e+10  1.485967e+10  1.786821e+07    830.092646    804.83
2017-01-13  1.512504e+10  1.512248e+10  1.786821e+07    846.477712    823.98
2017-01-14  1.502278e+10  1.502227e+10  1.786821e+07    840.754467    818.41
2017-01-15  1.510007e+10  1.510195e+10  1.786821e+07    845.079931    821.80
2017-01-16  1.524147e+10  1.527832e+10  1.786821e+07    852.993677    831.53
2017-01-17  1.657132e+10  1.661311e+10  1.786821e+07    927.419377    907.94
2017-01-18  1.621133e+10  1.625453e+10  1.786821e+07    907.271971    886.62
2017-01-19  1.643262e+10  1.647966e+10  1.786821e+07    919.656498    899.07
2017-01-20  1.639742e+10  1.644721e+10  1.786821e+07    917.686850    895.03
2017-01-21  1.686542e+10  1.691914e+10  1.786821e+07    943.878757    921.79
2017-01-22  1.688961e+10  1.694587e+10  1.786821e+07    945.232585    924.67
2017-01-23  1.684464e+10  1.690302e+10  1.786821e+07    942.715586    921.01
2017-01-24  1.634702e+10  1.637133e+10  1.786821e+07    914.865825    892.69
2017-01-25  1.648173e+10  1.650857e+10  1.786821e+07    922.405363    901.54
2017-01-26  1.675006e+10  1.687011e+10  1.786821e+07    937.422375    917.59
2017-01-27  1.678323e+10  1.681587e+10  1.786821e+07    939.278885    919.75
2017-01-28  1.682952e+10  1.686011e+10  1.786821e+07    941.869125    921.59
2017-01-29  1.679111e+10  1.691622e+10  1.786821e+07    939.719490    919.50
2017-01-30  1.683519e+10  1.696052e+10  1.786821e+07    942.186483    920.38
2017-01-31  1.766479e+10  1.779785e+10  1.786821e+07    988.615672    970.40
2017-02-01  1.809941e+10  1.809941e+10  1.830783e+07    988.615672    989.02
2017-02-02  1.847912e+10  1.848170e+10  1.830783e+07   1009.356006   1011.80
2017-02-03  1.880112e+10  1.880635e+10  1.830783e+07   1026.944047   1029.91
2017-02-04  1.903930e+10  1.904704e+10  1.830783e+07   1039.953799   1042.90
2017-02-05  1.877801e+10  1.878827e+10  1.830783e+07   1025.681872   1027.34
2017-02-06  1.896561e+10  1.897818e+10  1.830783e+07   1035.928916   1038.15
2017-02-07  1.935379e+10  1.936918e+10  1.830783e+07   1057.131770   1061.35
2017-02-08  1.937736e+10  1.939528e+10  1.830783e+07   1058.419176   1063.07
2017-02-09  1.818439e+10  1.820575e+10  1.830783e+07    993.257776    994.38
2017-02-10  1.811427e+10  1.813799e+10  1.830783e+07    989.427575    988.67
2017-02-11  1.838660e+10  1.841293e+10  1.830783e+07   1004.302547   1004.45
2017-02-12  1.830944e+10  1.833799e+10  1.830783e+07   1000.087695    999.18
2017-02-13  1.815534e+10  1.818621e+10  1.830783e+07    991.670516    990.64
2017-02-14  1.857273e+10  1.860746e+10  1.830783e+07   1014.469234   1004.55
2017-02-15  1.862881e+10  1.866601e+10  1.830783e+07   1017.532446   1007.48
2017-02-16  1.894858e+10  1.898869e+10  1.830783e+07   1034.998854   1027.44
2017-02-17  1.923446e+10  1.927754e+10  1.830783e+07   1050.613880   1046.21
2017-02-18  1.938793e+10  1.943389e+10  1.830783e+07   1058.996635   1054.42
2017-02-19  1.927614e+10  1.932418e+10  1.830783e+07   1052.890301   1047.87
2017-02-20  1.974667e+10  1.979805e+10  1.830783e+07   1078.591349   1079.98
2017-02-21  2.033043e+10  2.038567e+10  1.830783e+07   1110.477134   1115.30
2017-02-22  2.037071e+10  2.042910e+10  1.830783e+07   1112.677222   1117.44
2017-02-23  2.124378e+10  2.130845e+10  1.830783e+07   1160.365690   1166.72
2017-02-24  2.133887e+10  2.140670e+10  1.830783e+07   1165.559888   1173.68
2017-02-25  2.089743e+10  2.096735e+10  1.830783e+07   1141.447928   1143.84
2017-02-26  2.134801e+10  2.142308e+10  1.830783e+07   1166.059089   1165.20
2017-02-27  2.166124e+10  2.174051e+10  1.830783e+07   1183.168128   1179.97
2017-02-28  2.172997e+10  2.181290e+10  1.830783e+07   1186.922032   1179.97
2017-03-01  2.273088e+10  2.273088e+10  1.915111e+07   1186.922032   1222.50
2017-03-02  2.335813e+10  2.336408e+10  1.915111e+07   1219.674683   1251.01
2017-03-03  2.384252e+10  2.385184e+10  1.915111e+07   1244.968022   1274.99
```

Comment: Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Because too many rows and hard test solution

Comment: @jezrael Thank you for pointing out on this article. I have changed the example.

Comment: @jezral Thank you for your solution, but I think that my question was not very clear.I have changed it and add the code with the output that I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
#remove uunecessary columns and rename original Divisor
index_df = index_df.drop(['BTC','Index'], 1).rename(columns={'Divisor':'Divisor1'})

#your solution from answer for compare
index_df['Divisor'] = np.nan
index_df['Divisor'].loc['2017-01-01':'2017-01-31'] = index_df['Total.Cap'].loc['2017-01-01']/1000

index_df['Divisor'].loc['2017-02-01':'2017-02-28'] = index_df['Divisor'].loc['2017-01-01'] * (index_df['Real.Cap'].loc['2017-02-01']/index_df['Total.Cap'].loc['2017-01-31'])

index_df['Divisor'].loc['2017-03-01':'2017-03-31'] = index_df['Divisor'].loc['2017-02-01'] * (index_df['Real.Cap'].loc['2017-03-01']/index_df['Total.Cap'].loc['2017-02-28'])
index_df['Divisor'] = index_df['Divisor'].round()
index_df = index_df.rename(columns={'Divisor':'Divisor2'})
```

New solution - idea is working with month period data with [`cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumprod.html):

```
#filter first day of months
df  = index_df.set_index(index_df.index.to_period('m'))
df_first_day = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
#shift one month
df_first_day_shifted = df_first_day .shift()

#filter last day of months
df_last_day = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
df_last_day_shifted = df_last_day.shift()

val = df_first_day.loc['2017-01', 'Total.Cap'] / 1000 
s = (df_first_day['Real.Cap'] / df_last_day_shifted['Total.Cap']).fillna(val).cumprod().round()

index_df['Divisor'] = s.to_timestamp()
index_df['Divisor'] = index_df['Divisor'].ffill()
```

---

```
print (index_df)
               Total.Cap      Real.Cap    Divisor1    Divisor2     Divisor
Date                                                                      
2017-01-01  1.786821e+10  1.786821e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-02  1.830125e+10  1.830378e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-03  1.879293e+10  1.879827e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-04  2.081866e+10  2.082756e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-05  1.836418e+10  1.837429e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-06  1.649646e+10  1.650785e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-07  1.654743e+10  1.656090e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-08  1.663336e+10  1.664929e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-09  1.651083e+10  1.652868e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-10  1.662196e+10  1.664233e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-11  1.435626e+10  1.437583e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-12  1.483227e+10  1.485967e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-13  1.512504e+10  1.512248e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-14  1.502278e+10  1.502227e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-15  1.510007e+10  1.510195e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
2017-01-16  1.524147e+10  1.527832e+10  17868210.0  17868210.0  17868210.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I believe my questions wasn't very clear. I have changed the questions and added the logic that I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: @rakamakafo - yes, also is possible add exected output to question, how looks final dataframe?

Comment: thank you, I have added the expected dataframe output.

Comment: So what are input data and expected output? I am a bit confused.

Comment: input data are Total.Cap and Real.Cap. Divisor is expected output.

Comment: Do you have any solution by chance? Thanks

Comment: thank you so much for your solution. It is working as expected!